# How to negotiate salary while training (but ahead a promotion).?

Tags: promotion, training

I'm getting a promotion as a team leader in my company. I joint the company just 3 months ago and my training period is end by this month. From the first 1st of next month the promotion should be effective. But I will still be in the probation period for next 3 months. I'm in a doubt that if my pay increments would be held until my confirmation of service. My superior told he will be able to negotiate some good amount for me. But that isn't official. Days are getting close, but boss and me are not talking about it.

So, how can I approach my boss or his superior to clarify this without weakening my negotiation position on salary.?

Answer (score 2):

Just talk to him?

Ask for a quick chat, then when you're in his office or similar, bring it up in a "I just wanted to clarify a few things my promotion, responsibilities and the pay increase we discussed" way. Talk about when the promotion will be active, what the responsibilities etc will be and, of course, your pay.

I'm sure you have more questions than purely "When is my salary going up and can we talk about how much it will be?" so use this opportunity to clarify responsibilities etc too - a clearer understanding of your responsibilities will help you to better value how much you'd like to be compensated for that additional responsibility, and also give you more scope to negotiate based on those responsibilities.

Comment: Adding to this, make sure you get the promise of pay increase in writing before your probation period is over. Make sure the exact amount of the pay increase is in that writing. Without this, they can quite easily say that they never promised you anything. If they won't put it in writing, go look for a new job.